# Deploy Angular 7 and .Net 4.7 Web API in Godaddy

Tags: .net, angular, web-deployment

I have 2 solutions 1.Angular 7 application 2. .Net Web Api 
and have a windows hosting space in godaddy . I need to host these applications in godaddy .Please suggest me a solution for this . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install IIS first on your hosting space, then deploy you apps there. If you have enough space, I recommend to install all neccesary tools (Sql server, probably Visual studio) there and transfer your projects there ... will save a lot of time. Then, after publishing of apps, you can delete projects and these tools and free up the space.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2